# Python: Dictionary of Lists - Average return from input

Tags: python

I need to consider a list of students, create a dictionary and then from an input I have to return the average from the student.

You guys already helped me with this:

I need to return the value of my average calculation, but it's not working.

```
StudentGrades = {
"Alcott": [5, 9, 7],
"Jerry": [3, 5, 2],
"David": [8, 9, 8, 9]
}

## I fixed this, thank you
print("Students:")
for x, y in StudentGrades.items():
    print(x, y)

while True:
    print("Select a student: ")
    name = str(input())

    if name in StudentGrades.keys():
        print("You have chosen: " + name)
        print (res = sum(StudentGrades[name]/len(StudentGrades[name]))
    else:
        print('You chosen wrong!')
       break

## Also, I didn't wrap right John's value, thank you for showing me
#use of update function

print("Original Dictionary:")
print(StudentGrades)

StudentGrades.update(student)
print("Dictionary after update:")
print (StudentGrades)

#John's Average (not working? int object is not iterable)
res = sum(StudentGrades["John"]) / len(StudentGrades["John"])
print("John's average is:[10]/1 =" + str(res))
```

But I was also wondering if I could return something like this:

```
#Alcott's average
resAlcott = sum(StudentGrades["Alcott"]) / len(StudentGrades["Alcott"])


print("Students:")
for x, y in StudentGrades.items():
    print(x, y)

while True:
    print("Select a student: ")
    name = str(input())

    if name in StudentGrades.keys() == "Alcott":
        print("You have chosen: " + name + "'s average is", StudentGrades["Alcott"], resAlcott)
        
        
    else:
        print('You chosen wrong!')
        break
```

Thank you and I'm sorry again.

Comment: Miss `sum(StudentGrades[name]/len(StudentGrades[name])` this is not how the average is calculated. What you want is `sum(StudentGrades[name])/len(StudentGrades[name])`.

Comment: `res = sum(StudentGrades["Alcott"]) / len(StudentGrades["Alcott"])` See this one you're doing it right here but inside of the `while` loop there is a little error which you can fix easily.

Comment: What you want is `{"John": [10]}`, don't forget to wrap the `10` inside of the brackets.

Comment: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: I strongly recommend you looking at [how to ask questions on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I'm surprised how nobody down voted your post but still you must know what Stack Overflow is and how the questions have been asked.

Comment: hi Vicotria and welcome to SO. It seems like you had a follow up question. Please ask those in a new post, so your old question is still focused on a single thing and also so that all the current answers are not invalidated

Comment: Also please upvote/accept answers that where helpful/correct, to reward their effort ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
StudentGrades = {
"Alcott": [5, 9, 7], 
"Jerry": [3, 5, 2], 
"David": [8, 9, 8, 9]
}

print("Students:")
for x, y in StudentGrades.items():
    print(x, y)
 
while True:
    print("Select a student: ")
    name = str(input())
 
    if name in StudentGrades.keys():
        print("You have chosen: " + name)
        print( sum(StudentGrades[name]) / len(StudentGrades[name]) ). # This is the part of your code that was wrong.
    else:
        print('You chosen wrong!')
        break
```

Also, to add a new student you should NOT use `student = {'Name': 10}`, instead it should be `student = {'Name': [10]}`. The value must be a list, like all the others.

Comment: And also the way average is calculated for student `"John"`.

Comment: Oh yeah. I updated my answer to address this too. The problem is that she created the student with a different data structure than the others.

Answer (score 0):

I think you needs to make to change here. First would be to break down

```
print (res = sum(StudentGrades[name]/len(StudentGrades[name]))
```

into 2 lines and fix the parenthesis issues to get

```
res = sum(StudentGrades[name])/len(StudentGrades[name])
print(res)
```

The second change you need to make is changing the updated student from

```
student = {'John': 10}
```

to

```
student = {'John': [10]}
```

So that it is possible to iterate through his score(s)

```
StudentGrades = {
"Alcott": [5, 9, 7],
"Jerry": [3, 5, 2],
"David": [8, 9, 8, 9]
}

print("Students:")
for x, y in StudentGrades.items():
    print(x, y)

while True:
    print("Select a student: ")
    name = str(input())

    if name in StudentGrades.keys():
        print("You have chosen: " + name)
        res = sum(StudentGrades[name])/len(StudentGrades[name])
        print(res)
    else:
        print('You chosen wrong!')
        break

#Alcott's average
res = sum(StudentGrades["Alcott"]) / len(StudentGrades["Alcott"])

print("Alcott's average is:[5,9,7]/3 =" + str(res))

#Jerry's Average
res = sum(StudentGrades["Jerry"]) / len(StudentGrades["Jerry"])
limited_res = round(res,2)
print("Jerry's average is:[3,5,2]/3 =" + str(limited_res))

#David's Average
res = sum(StudentGrades["David"]) / len(StudentGrades["David"])

print("David's average is:[8,9,8,9]/4 =" + str(res))

student = {'John': [10]}

#use of update function

print("Original Dictionary:")
print(StudentGrades)

StudentGrades.update(student)
print("Dictionary after update:")
print (StudentGrades)

#John's Average (not working? int object is not iterable)
res = sum(StudentGrades["John"]) / len(StudentGrades["John"])
print("John's average is:[10]/1 =" + str(res))
```